# Configuring an installer to enable/disable startup on Windows start

Tags: windows, wix

I am trying to install an application for Windows 8.1 onwards so that it can be enabled and disabled to startup on Windows start both from the TaskManager and from Windows > Settings > Apps. The registry is being created like this:

```
<RegistryValue Id="myProgram.exe" 
               Root="HKLM"
               Action="write"
               Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" 
               Name="My Program" 
               Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]myProgram.exe" 
               Type="string"/>
```

This successfully adds the program to the startup applications list, and it can be disabled / enabled from the Task Manager but cannot be controlled from Windows > Settings > Apps. The application shows up in the Windows Settings list, but you can tell toggling the enable / disable doesn't change anything by going into the registry and seeing that the value at HLM\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run\My Program does not change. Why is Windows Settings not able to control this startup application?

Also, if we want to pre-enter a value for enabling / disabling startup at HLM\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run\My Program, which binary value would we use for each option?

Comment: Have you checked whether the setting was applied after a reboot? I would consider it a Windows bug, if the settings app cannot disable autorun entries that are registered under HKLM. If it cannot do so with normal user rights, it should ask to elevate.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the feedback, it seems that the settings app cannot disable autorun for any HKLM and will only change settings for HKCU. We also thought it was a bug but some articles point to it being by design now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this website https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-or-remove-startup-apps-in-windows-10/   the "Modern"  startup apps system setting only applies to Run key in HKCU.

I've not tested this article.  You might want to use profiling tools such as registry snapshot/diff and/or processexplorer to verify what this new settings screen is doing.

Comment: Thanks for this response. This is indeed the behavior I observed when switching the registry key to HKCU.

Answer (score 0):

***HKCU***: I am not sure, and I can't test right now. Trying some hints. As Chris indicates: why do you write to **`HKLM`**? Change it to **`HKCU`** and see if that works:

```
<RegistryValue Id="myProgram.exe" 
           Root="HKCU"
           Action="write"
           Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" 
           Name="My Program" 
           Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]myProgram.exe" 
           Type="string"/>
```

***Autoruns***: There is a tool from SysInternals that is good to use when checking auto-run issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns. And a [direct run from source link](https://live.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe). Using this tool it seems that when disabling an item in the list, they are moved to a sub-key called **`AutorunsDisabled`**:

[image: AutorunsDisabled]

Comment: It always smells bad to me if an all-users setup writes something to `HKCU`. Only works if the user who runs the setup, is the same who is using the program. Won't work for network installations and multiple users working on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, true. Depends what options you have. Anything in `HKCU` should be writable by the application, but deployments can have no launchable applications. I don't deploy anything in `HKCU` if I can help it.